# Rails: Two values for label_method (simple_form_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form-for

I want to create a new pm_workload. I have the following code-snippet

```
<%= f.input :project_id, :collection => PmProject.order('name'), :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, :label => "Project", :include_blank => false %>
```

Is there an option to use two values for :label_method? e.g. 

`:label_method => :name << (PmProject.project_number)`

Comment: you need label_method should be concatenate of name & project_number ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to try because I have sometimes the same project name but different project numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to have to attributes or field name inside the label method. But I have an alternate soluction for you resolve this problem.

You are taking PmProject collections, So now create a instance level method insdie the PmProject model like as below.

```
def name_of_method
  "#{name} #{project_number}"
end
```

Now to use the same on the view input of the simple form for use like that as below...

```
<%= f.input :project_id, :collection => PmProject.order('name'), :label_method => :name_of_method, :value_method => :id, :label => "Project", :include_blank => false %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I've tried your solution but I get this error message: undefined method `name_of_method' for #<PmProject:0x007f0d8beb77c0>

Comment: Oh god I'm so stupid... You're totally right. This is the right way to solve my problem. Thank you. I've made the mistake and put the def name_of_method... in the controller not in the model

Comment: Do not write it inside the private block, and try to get the same method work inside the console on the pmpobject.

Comment: Yeah, what ever the formatting you need on the attributes you need to put into the model not in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at this problem this week. But a variation of it, in my case I wanted the label text to be wrapped in a <span>. I thought I was looking for was related to simple_form but actually it's still part of Rails ActionView tags helpers.

Yes, you could add another method on your model, but if you like to keep your models clean or you want to use something not in the model in the label. :label_method can also be a proc.

```
<% label_method = proc { |p| "#{p.name} #{p.project_number}" } %>
<%= f.input :project_id, collection: PmProject.order('name'), label_method: label_method, value_method :id, label: 'Project', include_blank: false %>
```

or in my case

```
<% label_method = proc { |p| "<span>#{p.name}</span>".html_safe } %>
<%= f.input :project_id, collection: PmProject.order('name'), label_method: label_method, value_method :id, label: 'Project', include_blank: false %>
```